# A space is homotopy equivalent to its Kolmogorov quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

My professor mentioned that every finite topological space is homotopy equivalent to its Kolmogorov quotient, but it seems to me that this should be true for any topological space.

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be its Kolmogorov quotient (that is, $Y=X/\sim$ under the quotient topology where $x_1\sim x_2$ iff for all open sets, $U$, $x_1\in U$ if and only if $x_2\in U$). Let $f:X\to Y$ be the canonical surjection and let $g:Y\to X$ be any choice function. Then $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $f\circ g=id_Y$. Define $H:X\times[0,1]\to X$ by $H(x,0)=(g\circ f)(x)$ and $H(x,t)=x$ for any $t>0$. Since $g(f(x))$ is topologically indistinguishable from $x$, $(g\circ f)^{-1}(U)=U$ for any open set $U\subset X$. So, $H^{-1}(U)=U\times[0,1]$ for any open set $U$ which implies $H$ is continuous. Thus $g\circ f\simeq id_X$ so that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct: the Kolmogorov quotient map of any topological space is a homotopy equivalence, with any section as a homotopy inverse.